# How to set the default APN for SIMCARD2 programmatically

Tags: android, sim-card

I have an application that runs under system account and one of the features is create custom APNs depending the client's configurations.

The code below works fine, but just create the APN and set it as default for simcard 1. O would like to set it depending on simcards if the software is running on Android 5 or above. I could not find any documentation about it. Anyone knows something else about APNs?

```
    public static int createNewApn(Context context, APN apn, boolean setAsDefaultAPN) {
    int apnid = -1;

    try {
        if (apn != null) {
            Uri APN_URI = Uri.parse("content://telephony/carriers");
            ContentResolver resolver = context.getContentResolver();
            ContentValues values = prepareValues(apn);
            Cursor c = null;
            Uri newRow = resolver.insert(APN_URI, values);

            if (newRow != null) {
                c = resolver.query(newRow, null, null, null, null);

                int tableIndex = c.getColumnIndex("_id");
                c.moveToFirst();
                apnid = c.getShort(tableIndex);
            }

            if (c != null) {
                c.close();
            }

            if (apnid > -1 && setAsDefaultAPN) {
                ContentValues v = new ContentValues(1);
                v.put("apn_id", apnid);

                context.getContentResolver().update(APN_PREFER_URI, v, null, null);
            }
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return apnid;
}
```